# angular if else problem with passing 2 data

Tags: angular

Im using hard coded login. I have 3 type of user.

```
  if(this.loginForm.value.email == 'admin' && this.loginForm.value.password == 'admin'){
    console.log(`found corresponding user.`);
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home']);
  }


  if(this.loginForm.value.email == 'USapparel&textile' && this.loginForm.value.password == 'admin'){
    console.log(`found corresponding user.`);
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home', {company_id: '39'}]);
  }

  if(this.loginForm.value.email == 'USapparel&textile0118/003' && this.loginForm.value.password == 'admin'){
    console.log(`found corresponding user.`);
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home', {company_id: '39', policy_id: 'IGT/D/PHI3/0000000001/0118/003'}]);
  }
```

Im passing data in one im not passing any thing , in second company_id and in third company_id and policy_id .

in home component

```
if(this.company_id){
    this.getSamad(this.company_id);
     this.company = false;
  }
if(this.policy_id){
     this.getSamad2(this.policy_id);
    this.company = false;
  }
```

I have 2 function getSamad and getSamad2 . but when im only company_id its also use getSamad2 function. Mean im only passing company_id so it will use getSamad function ? but its using getSamad2 function . any one can help how ill do this ?

Comment: Btw not clear to me! Do you want that both param in the navigated page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the value of "this.policy_id" when you do not send a value for it. In that case it could not be null but empty or something else.

Comment: Yes you are right its null thats why how can i do it empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(this.policy_id) {
  // policy_id available
}
else {
  // policy_id not available
}
```

and If you want to send it as a parameter then for first navigate method

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home', {company_id: '39', policy_id : null }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT HARDCODE EXPLICITE PASSWORDS in your ANGULAR APP** (at least hash them)

Try

```
if(this.company_id){
    this.getSamad(this.company_id);
    this.company = false;
} else if(this.policy_id){
    this.getSamad2(this.policy_id);
    this.company = false;
}
```